# How do i get Google Container Registry to accept my json credentials?

Tags: json, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, google-container-registry

I am trying to use Google Container Registry with GitLab CI without using the gcloud interface.

Using the docs listed here under the section "Using a JSON key file":
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

I've downloaded my service account credentials file as a JSON file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "REDACTED",
  "private_key_id": "REDACTED",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nBIGLONGLISTOFGARBLEDTEXTNSTUFF\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "somethingsomething@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "NUMBERSNUMBERSNUMBERS",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/somethingsomething%40developer.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I've then tried logging in using the specified command:

```
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat google_cred.json)" https://gcr.io
```

That yields the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

`docker login https://gcr.io` presents me with a username/password interactive prompt, so it isn't a problem with my local docker installation as far as I can tell.

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is now very easy:

```
cat google_cred.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

I suggest to add the --config option. a.e:

```
cat google_cred.json | docker --config /tmp/dockerconf login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

Using docker with "docker --config /configfile" is more robust especially with docker in docker scenarios.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Hi @starteleport I guess the confusion was because of the --config option. I edited my reply to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your client cannot talk to your Docker daemon, I assume something as simple as `docker ps` returns the same message?

Do you need a `sudo` in front of the command?  How do you typically invoke  Docker?

Comment: `docker ps` or any other docker commands work fine, including `docker login https://gcr.io`; the latter presents me with a username/password prompt, but no way to supply json file as a credential at that point. I believe it has something to do with the format of the JSON credential file (with all the special characters and newlines), but i can't say for certain and there's really no way to diagnose.

Comment: What version of docker are you using? I tried exactly the same and I don't have problem using JSON key file. Have you checked what your docker daemon log file says? You may want to enable the debug mode of daemon to get more information

Comment: `Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec`. I have not checked the log file. I did not know that such a thing existed. :D

Comment: Please check your docker daemon logs. Or you can stop your docker service and run dockerd with -D option directly from a terminal, and keep the terminal open, then run your "docker login -u ..." command, and see what output you get from the dockerd terminal

Answer (score 0):

One needs to be sure to be connected to the Google Compute Engine instance via your local docker before attempting to login with docker. So the command sequence (on macOS) is something like:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<your-cred.json>
eval $(docker-machine env <your-google-instance>)
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat <your-cred.json>)" https://gcr.io
```